# What are the problems in connecting Azure VM and HDInsight Cluster in different regions

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, region, azure-hdinsight

I am creating Azure VM and installing my application (say as app1) on it in EAST US region.

I am creating HDInsight Spark cluster and installing my application (say as app2) on it in CENTRAL US region.

Now I configure app2 IP with app1 on Azure VM.

What are the issues will occur if we have Azure VM and HDInsight cluster in different region?

Comment: Do you mean connect app2 to app1? through public network?

Comment: No. I will configure app2 Private IP in app1 properties.

Comment: We can deploy VPN between them, then we can configure them with Priviate IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I will configure app2 Private IP in app1 properties

If you want to configure app2 private IP in app1 properties, we should deploy a VPN between different regions.

Comment: Ya Ok. What is difference between connecting between different regions and same region. Is there any data latency in different region or some other issue?

Comment: @karan As far as I know, different regions with different data latency, we can use this tool to test azure speed,http://azurespeedtest.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read these articles for configuring HDInsight in VNets:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-extend-hadoop-virtual-network#virtual-network-requirements

The "Configure two virtual networks in two different regions" section in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hbase-replication